# rspec check 'with' argument is true

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have the following rspec example:

```
describe "with spike" do
  it "succeeds" do
    a = double('whatever')

    a.should_receive(:b).with(true)

    a.b('not false')
  end
end
```

How can I make `with` accept any non-false argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write an arbitrary message handler:

```rb
describe "with spike" do
  it "succeeds" do
    a = double('whatever')

    a.should_receive(:b) { |x|
      x.should_not be_false
    }

    a.b('not false')
  end
end
```